# How to store maps to a firestore array

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, maps

I have xyz document inside abc collection.

- I want to add a **map** to **an array** inside **document xyz**.

I can add a single array item using this code

```
CollectionReference collection = this.collection(collection);
DocumentReference ref = collection.document(document);
ref.setData({"data": FieldValue.arrayUnion(values)});
```

here **data** is the parent array.

but when I try to add another **map** , firestore **replace the values** of index **0** , it **does not add map to next index**  means to index 1,2,3 or .....

let see the example
here is the map

```
    values = {
        "tokens": "99",
        "title": "Cleaning",
        "location": {"  lat": "34.4333", "lng": "53.4343"},
        "id": "gVnGE5ZPRnQ8HYQq7dvT",
        "client": "LFBXXj7Zi0xOr0FqBGID",
        "date": "22/8/2019",
        "message": "request message...",
        "budget": "150",
        "details": {
        "  When would you like to have the cleaners over?":
            "week",
        "What type of cleaning package would you prefer?":
            "answer for the type of clean",
        "Do you need the cleaning tools and materials?":
            "false",
        "What time do you prefer to have the cleaners over?":
            "8/20/2019"
        }
    }
```

and I want to add it as new array item each time when I send data to the firestore

eg.

```
    onTap() {
        CollectionReference collection = this.collection(collection);
        DocumentReference ref = collection.document(document);
        ref.setData({"value": FieldValue.arrayUnion(values)});
    }
```

---

here is the code

```
    var values = {
        "tokens": "99",
        "title": "Cleaning",
        "location": {"  lat": "34.4333", "lng": "53.4343"},
        "id": "gVnGE5ZPRnQ8HYQq7dvT",
        "client": "LFBXXj7Zi0xOr0FqBGID",
        "date": "22/8/2019",
        "message": "request message...",
        "budget": "150",
        "details": {
        "  When would you like to have the cleaners over?":
            "week",
        "What type of cleaning package would you prefer?":
            "answer for the type of clean",
        "Do you need the cleaning tools and materials?":
            "false",
        "What time do you prefer to have the cleaners over?":
            "8/20/2019"
        }
    }

    onTap() {
        CollectionReference collection = this.collection(collection);
        DocumentReference ref = collection.document(document);
        ref.setData({"value": FieldValue.arrayUnion(values)});
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `setData` function which overwrites your existing values. You need to use `updateData` function instead which will add the value to the existing array. Just change your `onTap` function to this:

```
onTap() {
        CollectionReference collection = this.collection(collection);
        DocumentReference ref = collection.document(document);
        ref.updateData({"value": FieldValue.arrayUnion(values)});
}
```